# Generate uuid in size of 16 and datatype : binary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

To generate uuid for 16bit binary datatype in rails

I have used this 'SecureRandom.uuid' but it takes very big size.
It takes big size, and i have binary(16)  datatype and size, database=mysql; uuid = SecureRandom.uuid

I want 16 sized uuid and store in binary datatype.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please create a minimal woking example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
require 'securerandom'
uuid = SecureRandom.hex 16
```

In a typical model you'd do:

```
before_create :set_uuid
def set_uuid
  self.uuid ||= SecureRandom.hex 16 # or self.id, whatever your attribute is named
end
```

If you are using PG it has nice support for UUID with little toll on performance so you can just define uuid columns in your migrations. https://lab.io/articles/2017/04/13/uuids-rails-5-1/

Comment: Ok Thanks but hex(16) are taking 32 size so i have use hex(8), now it's taking 16 sized and worked successfully.